# Directly scroll to a particular image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jsp

I've provided a link with every image uploaded by the user which takes the  user to a Slider to scroll through all the images that a user has uploaded on my site.The path of all the images uploaded by the user has been stored in a database.

Now, what I want is that when a user clicks on a particular image the slider directly scrolls to that image and all the other images are arranged according to their respective positions in the database,i.e., those uploaded before that particular image are displayed before and similarly those uploaded after the image are displayed after the particular image in the slider.

The slider uses the `<li>` tag to list the images in order. How can I perform the required task?

I'll also put up my code below:

```
<%
     String lnk6 = "slider2.jsp?posted_id="+image_id;
 %>
<a href = "<%=lnk6%>" ><img src = "<%=lnk%>" width = "500px" height = "400px" /> </a>
```

This is the page where my image is being displayed. The string variable "lnk6" provides a link to the Slider. "image_id" is a variable, which is obtained above in the code(which I'm not displaying), provides the ID for a particular image.Now my code in Slider:

```
int id_show = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("image_id"));
PreparedStatement pstmt_show = conn.prepareStatement("select image,text from post where posted_id=?");
pstmt_show.setInt(1, id_show);
ResultSet rst_show = pstmt_show.executeQuery();
while(rst_show.next())
{
    img_show = rst_show.getString(1);
    text_show = rst_show.getString(2);
    if(!(img_show.equals("")))
    {
        link_show = "./postimages/"+img_show;
%>
        <li><img src="<%=link_show%>" title="<%=text_show%>" />            
</li>

<%
    }
}
%>
```

"post" is the table where all the images uploaded by the user are stored.

Comment: Are you using any particular plugin?

Comment: in  upload-success callback, you can set ``#newimage`` to that image's anchor and tell jquery to go there

Comment: @doniyor Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Put an anchor where yo want to go

```
    <a name='destinaton'></a>
```

And a link to this anchor on your picture

```
    <a href="#destinaton">
```

Use JQuery a smooth Scroll to make it more user friendly :)

http://plugins.jquery.com/smooth-scroll/

Comment: The main issue is that I'm using a "while" loop to get all my images from the database and ``<li>`` is placed inside this while loop so these are created automatically for all the images.So how can I add a link to that particular image which I want to display?

Comment: Whenever you are placing li in that loop , place this <a...> </a> too inside that <li> tag.

Comment: @Abhinav Gauniyal Can you please elaborate where I've to place these two anchor tags. I've a JSP page where I've provided the link to my Slider which is in a new JSP page.

Comment: inside the li tags , wherever they are concurring inside the while loop. I can't see any of your code from here , so i cannot exactly predict.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I've also uploded my code in the question. Now if you can suggest something as I'm not able to understand what I can do make the required thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create seperate ID for every image you place. And every ID will scroll to that particular image so that should be unique. I think there's a variable image_id defined for that.

CODE:

```
int id_show = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("image_id"));
PreparedStatement pstmt_show = conn.prepareStatement("select image,text from post where posted_id=?");
pstmt_show.setInt(1, id_show);
ResultSet rst_show = pstmt_show.executeQuery();
while(rst_show.next())
{
    img_show = rst_show.getString(1);
    text_show = rst_show.getString(2);
    if(!(img_show.equals("")))
    {
        link_show = "./postimages/"+img_show;
%>
        <li><img src="<%=link_show%>" title="<%=text_show%>" id="<%=image_id%>" />            
</li>

<%
    }
}
%>
```

And for navigation part ,

```
%
   String lnk6 = /*"slider2.jsp?posted_id="+image_id;*/
%>
<a href = "<%=lnk6%>" ><img src = "<%=lnk%>" width = "500px" height = "400px" /> </a>
```

Please check the code for syntax errors , I don't know much of this language.